# Browser sync and connect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, browser-sync

I have problem with browser sync and localhost:8000. When I try to submit a form request I get `TokenMismatchException`. How can I solve this?

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('connect-sync', function() {
var connect = require('gulp-connect-php');
connect.server({
    base: 'public',
    port: 8000,
    router: '../server.php',
    watch: true
}, function (){
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'localhost:8000'
    });
});

  var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
  gulp.task('reload', function(){
      browserSync.reload();
  }); 
});
```